# Магия Java. Размер массива и выход за границу

Tags: java

```
String[] IpMask;   
Task = in.readUTF();   
IpMask = Task.split("-");
ThisServerFrame.Tip.setText(IpMask[0].toString());   
ThisServerFrame.Tmask.setText(IpMask[1].toString());
```

Получаю строчку по сокету, хочу ее засплитить на несколько строк. Показывает, что длина итогового массива разобранной строки — 2, но при обращении

```
ThisServerFrame.Tmask.setText(IpMask[1].toString());
```

я получаю выход за границы массива.

Comment: Вопрос в том, почему я получаю `exception` или как организовать грамотный подход к считыванию элементов массива?

Comment: Почему в массиве длиной 2 я получаю ошибку при обращении к элементу с индексом 1

Comment: Вы уверены, что получаете `exception` для `IpMask[1]`? Может `setText` пытается прописать куда-то не те данные?

Comment: он в текстбокс пишет из массива, ошибка именно в массиве

Comment: Ну хорошо, прежде чем попросить лог ошибки, распечатка элемента `IpMask[1]` что даёт?

Comment: она не дает ничего, исключение же бросается:)

Comment: Попробуйте прокрутить for each и отрисовать результат для каждой итерации.

Comment: @Печенька Молоке: попробуйте так:

    String tip = IpMask[0].toString();
    ThisServerFrame.Tip.setText(tip);
    String tmask = IpMask[1].toString();
    ThisServerFrame.Tmask.setText(tmask);

и посмотрите, какая из строк вылетает.

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, что массив содержит лишь один элемент. Проблема в том, что вы прочитали из сокета.

Учтите, что для строки "zzz-" split вернет массив из одного элемента, а для "-" - пустой массив.

Comment: Но у меня размер получвшегося массива равен 2, и из него я читаю элемент с индексом 1. Вне работы с сокетами это работает на ура

Comment: Тот факт, что вне работы с сокетами это работает на ура, только доказывает мое утверждение. Нет никакой магии.

Comment: А в чем различается строчка прошедшая через сеть от той,которая этого не делала?
444-454 одна и та же строка. Причем в случае с сокетом, она успешно вся дошла. я пытаюсь ее разбить

Comment: @Печенька Молоке Вы уверены что ваша строка "вся дошла"? Выводили в лог/консоль содержимое строки? Или может смотрели значение строки в отладчике? А может вы правите один исходный код, а компилируете и запускаете другой.

Comment: @Печенька Молоке, Вы утверждаете, что

    System.out.println(""+IpMask.length);

**печатает число 2** и при обращении к IpMask[1] программа падает?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте коллекции. Вы никогда не сможете гарантировать что строка пришедшая извне будет размера 2+.

Информация для размышлений  [тут](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: Простите, а как связаны коллекции и размер приходящей строки?

Comment: при том, что проще обработать выход за пределы массива и не выходить за границу. Да и вообще это более крсивый и безопасный способ чем использование массивов.

По поводу размера приходящей строки ничего сказать не могу, так как очень нечетко сформулирован вопрос.

Comment: @Artemis Ну это-то все правильно - грамотная реализация подхода в коде к элементам массива при считывании или установке значений дает плюс к карме и вообще говорит о профессионализме программиста. Но вот как раз просто дело в том, что акцент автора вопроса был сконцентрирован на том, почему он получает `exception` при слепом обращении к элементу массива (который, возможно, мог бы быть за его пределами), зная наперед, что он должен быть, в то время как элемент массива не инициализировался из-за того, что данные, перед тем как попасть в `split`, не "приходили". А это уже другая опера.

Comment: Как закручено) Но я просто даже предположить не могу что прилетает после вызова in.readUTF(); Поэтому единственный адекватный способ избежать ошибки - подумать заранее что делать если чего-то все таки не прилетит. 
Иначе нужно прально формулировать вопрос.

Comment: @Artemis, 

    подумать заранее что делать ...

вот это правильно. 

А коллекции или просто массив - это безразлично. Если человек не способен программировать, то тут ничего не поможет. 

Судя по реакциии (точнее, ее отсутствии) на свой вопрос, автор именно таков.

Comment: ну я не был бы так категоричен я тоже часто забываю ответить на вопрос. Просто вопросы нужно формировать болеее точно - сложное исскуство оторое поможет в дальшейшем.

Comment: А если присмотреться, то нехило так народ подтянулся на решение проблемы, которая вроде и не проблема, а косяк где-то за пределами куска представленного скрипта. Солидарность что надо - не пропадём :)

Answer (score 2):

Эмм... Сокеты - вещь очень медленная, как показывает практика.
Есть вероятность, что сокет ещё принимает данные (ещё не все принял), а вы уже дергаете буфер. Разумеется, буфер вернет байты, но не в том количестве, что вы ожидаете. Другой вариант этой проблемы - программа редко дергает буфер сокета, и юзер получает склеившиеся пакеты.

Вариантов несколько:

1. Структурировать пакет таким образом, что первые 2 или 4 байта указывают на длину всего пакета. В цикле ждать, когда в буфере появятся 2/4 байта. Прочитать их. В цикле ждать, когда в буфере появится N байтов, прочтенных из предыдущего пункта, дальше дергать нужное N число байтов. Следующим за ними будет опять размерность следующего пакета.
2. Если пакеты бывают только одного формата, и всегда фиксированной длины - можно просто ждать, когда в буфере будет нужное число байтов, и затем прочитать нужное число байтов (не больше). Вариант не из лучших, является лентяйством.
3. Можно сделать заранее большой буфер, куда стекуются (FIFO) байты из буфера сокета, и по нужде дергать нужное количество байтов из этого своего стэка. Вариант не из лучших - велосипедизм, однако несколько раз встречал.

PS: Чтобы удостовериться о полученном, после

```
IpMask = Task.split("-");
```

вызовите:

```
System.out.println(Task + ", splits for " + IpMask.Length + "parts");
```

и посмотрите, что получится.

Comment: На предыдущее аналогичное предложение подтвердить, что `IpMask.Length` выводит в консоль значение **2**, автор вопроса ответа не дал.

Comment: Судя по всему, автор просто забил... :) Или решил проблему молча, с величайшей депрессией и стыдом, которые ему не позволяют доложить о результатах.

Comment: Я не забил) Извините, стоило сообщить, вы правы) Проблема решилась, она была как и часто бывает - не знаю в чем:) Когда она исчезла, я не запомнил, что  именно поменял, ибо вариантов перепробовал кучу. В памяти жиздится вариант с неправильно поданной строкой:(  Прошу прощения у коммьюнити за  такие вопросы.